# Why Elastic Search favorite JSON?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new beginner of Elastic Search. One feature I found is that elastic search documents is particularly expressed in JSON. I google a while but I can not found any reason about that.

Can someone help to explain why JSON not XML or other format?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I updated my question. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is because json document has key, value structure and it helps elasticsearch to index on basis of keys. Suppose if there is an XML, then a lot of effort will be required to just parse the data whereas in json , according to key value elastic search can directly index the required data.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are mainly 2 standard ways to transport data between a server and client,  XML and JSON. Old services use XML as well as JSON as a way to transfer data as most of the old consumers of the services are stick to XML parsers, but recent services use JSON as a standard mainly because of simplicity that comes with JSON. JSON parsers are easy to build and use. At the same time XML parsers needs to be customized as per fields. Although there are some great libraries for parsing a XML response like SAX parser in JAVA, its still not that straight forward. Also JSON can be directly used in javascript. I hope I have answered your question.